# Creating a custom portlet application for jboss gatein with its own lucene version

Tags: jboss, lucene, gatein

I'm trying to deploy a JSR-286 portlet application that has its own lucene version (3.1) packaged in WEB-INF/lib to JBoss GateIn.

For some reason it is giving me GateIn's lucene (2.9.4) classes during runtime and its therefore producing this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_31
```

Does anyone know how to configure the portlet application and GateIn to let it load its own lucene libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the error by creating a JBoss module and adding a dependency to the manifest of the war file.